# How do I add a composite check constraint that references a composite key?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, constraint

Given the following tables

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id               SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name             TEXT NOT NULL,
  email            TEXT NOT NULL,
  organization_id  TEXT NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (name, email)
);

CREATE TABLE tasks (
  id               SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  users_id         TEXT NOT NULL,
  organization_id  TEXT NOT NULL,
  description      TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Is it possible to create constraints for 'user_id' column , that i can use values form 'users' table only with the same organization_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A check constraint that references another table like that is called a [`FOREIGN KEY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html). You can do what you want with `MATCH FULL`

As a special note the types must be the same, so in your example `tasks.users_id` is text. It must be int (the underlying type of `users.id`).

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id               SERIAL,
  name             TEXT NOT NULL,
  email            TEXT NOT NULL,
  organization_id  int,
  PRIMARY KEY (organization_id, id),
  UNIQUE (name, email)
);

CREATE TABLE tasks (
  id               SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  organization_id  int  NOT NULL,
  users_id         int  NOT NULL,
  description      TEXT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (organization_id, users_id)
    REFERENCES users (organization_id, id) MATCH FULL
);
```

You can add the constriant after the fact like this..

```
ALTER TABLE tasks
  ADD CONSTRAINT asdf
  FOREIGN KEY (organization_id, users_id)
  REFERENCES users (organization_id, id)
  MATCH FULL;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I know about foreign keys. But my problem is as following: for example, in 'users' table i have two users with different organization_id (id:1, organization:1 and id:2, organization:2)  and then i insert new record in 'tasks'  with organization_id = 1 and user = 2 it should become impossible. Sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: @skyien check my update, see if that's what you want.

Comment: BTW It breaks the logic. It allows to do something like `insert into users (id, organization_id) values(1,1),(1,2)` thus `user.id` is not unique; and it is impossible to reference to the `user` table from any other tables which have not `organization_id` column. IMO additional constraint like `unique(organization_id, id)` instead of altering the primary key is better...

Comment: Just depends on if you want a surrogate key, or a natural key. If the key doesn't matter and the task belongs to the user with regard for what organization he is in, I would say ditch the org requirement entirely and just references on user_id.